# Codeception 2.2 api tests ZF2 and PhpBrowser module together

Tags: codeception

Codeception API tester require **PhpBrowser** module and I want to use **ZF2** module because I need retrieve some services from **ServiceManager**.

After update Codeception to 2.2 it throws this exception:

> [Codeception\Exception\ModuleConflictException] ZF2 module conflicts
>   with PhpBrowser

Is there any way to enable ZF2 and PhpBrowser together in Codeception 2.2?

Comment: No. Could you share your test code, I would like to see your use case.

Comment: Please consider reading [How to Create a Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try rewriting your question.

Comment: Actually the question is good, it just is very specific.

Comment: I added a new way to solve this issue to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a good reason to use ZF2 in the same suite as PhpBrowser,
you can create your own helper class and load ZF2 module as a dependency.

Configuration:

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://localhost/
        - \Helper\Zf2Helper:
            depends: ZF2
```

Code `tests/_support/Helper/Zf2Helper.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Helper;

class Zf2Helper extends \Codeception\Module
{

  private $zf2;

  public function _inject(\Codeception\Module\ZF2 $zf2)
  {
     $this->zf2 = $zf2;
  }

  public function doSomethingWithZf2
  {
     $this->zf2->doSomething();
  }
}
```

Update:

Since Codeception 2.2.2 release it is possible to load `services` part of ZF2 which enables `grabServiceFromContainer` method.

Configuration:

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://localhost/
        - ZF2
            part: services
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank your for your answer.

Working code with some improvements:

```
<?php
namespace Helper;

use Codeception\Lib\Interfaces\DependsOnModule;

class Zf2Helper extends \Codeception\Module implements DependsOnModule
{

    protected $dependencyMessage = <<<EOF
Example configuring ZF2Helper as proxy for ZF2 module method grabServiceFromContainer.
--
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\ZF2Helper:
            depends: ZF2
--
EOF;

    private $zf2;

    public function _inject(\Codeception\Module\ZF2 $zf2)
    {
        $this->zf2 = $zf2;
    }

    public function _depends()
    {
        return ['Codeception\Lib\ZF2' => $this->dependencyMessage];
    }

    public function grabServiceFromContainer($service)
    {
        return $this->zf2->grabServiceFromContainer($service);
    }
}
```